# Rank the dataframe values in R

Tags: r, sorting, rank

I want to fetch the row numbers of the first 5 highest values in a column in a dataframe and add a value of 100 on the same row number in another dataframe and rest other values as 0.

I know how to sort / order a column in a dataframe using order() function.

```
df=data.frame(a=c(345,948,290,189,3848,302,384,456,383,201,35,346,1.46,4.66,3,5,63,43,6432,4336,345,354,1245,342,523,743,248,932.5))
```

For example, `df[order(-df$a),]` results in

```
6432.00 4336.00 3848.00 1245.00  948.00  932.50  743.00  523.00  456.00  384.00  383.00  354.00 346.00  345.00  345.00  342.00  302.00  290.00  248.00  201.00  189.00   63.00   43.00   35.00   5.00    4.66    3.00    1.46
```

However, I am not able to meet my specific requirement.

I would expect to see df1 as

```
0 100 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 100 100 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use the `rank` function:

```
df$b <- (rank(-df$a) <= 5) * 100
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df$b <- ifelse(df$a %in% sort(df$a, T)[1:5], 100, 0)
```